# Setting Date and Time into Oracle Date field using ebean

Tags: java, oracle, playframework-2.0, ebean

Good old date/time problem which I can't to solve with good style...
DB: Oracle 11g
Table contains field: `upd_date` with Oracle type `DATE` - I can't change it to TIMESTAMP

My Ebean model:

```
@Column(name="UPD_DT")
public Timestamp uploadedAt;
```

I'm trying to save model with current timestamp and then check which value has been saved:

`model.uploadedAt = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

model.save();

System.out.println("Time before save:" + model.uploadedAt);

System.out.println("Time after save:" + Models.byId(model.id).uploadedAt;`

And getting following results:
`Time before save:1391633542210

Time after save:1391633542000`

I'm know that the difference in these fields because of Oracle `DATE` doesn't have milliseconds part, but if I will try to update this model object without changing uploadedAt field - I will get:  `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Data has changed.`

Is there any correct way to declare fields in JPA models for Oracle Date field with date and time included, when I don't need to change TimeSpamp every time when I want to update object?

P.S. : Creation like `new Timestamp((System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)*1000);` looks ugly and all others solution with cutting milliseconds in TimeStamp are very heavy.
I'm trying to find short and clear solution when I don't need to think about superfluous milliseconds.